# Could I buy a 3G router and have it broadcast WiFi around my house?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, 3g

I live at a place where the WiFi signal overshoots my house, and thanks to that I have to use dialup. My brother has an Android phone I think and he is able to browse the internet and stuff using 3G, which lead me to think about trying to get 3G. Could I buy a 3G router and have it broadcast WiFi around my house? I think you have to pay for 3G but I'm not entirely sure how it works. Any help or information would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, if you have 3G coverage you can buy a 3G router and it will act as any normal WiFi router (for example with cable access). All the clients will have internet access over 3G.

My advise would be: If your friend's phone is running Android 2.2 or higher, it has a built-in WiFi hotspot function. Try using this Android hotspot function and see if you can get good enough browsing speeds, otherwise using 3G as a primary internet connection is a bad idea and frustrating experience.

You will definitely have to pay for 3G. Check with your mobile phone providers for a cheap plan. They mostly have data-only plans available which include a certain traffic limit of e.g. 10 GB per month.

**Be advised:** 3G data plans can become very very very expensive when you shoot over the monthly limit. So make sure you buy enough traffic and watch it carefully.

Comment: My advice would be - try for 4G while you're at it. :)

Comment: My advice: Don't ever use 4G if they limit the usable data volume and limit the bandwidth to 384 kbit/s after you have used up the available data volume. Every single provider in germany does that (max 40GB/month with all available extras already purchased). Its much better for your sanity to take a shovel and bury a cable or glass fiber to the next place where there is a real internet connection available.